# Unable to cancel Sendgrid account on GoogleCloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, google-cloud-marketplace

I had implemented Sendgrid in a big project we have in Google Cloud. And subscribe to the Sendgrid Email API available in the Google Cloud Marketplace. But it took so much time to develop that the sendgrid account got deactivated.

Now the linked sendgrid account cant be use, and there is no way of linking a new account on the Google cloud platform.

I assumed that canceling the subscription and resubscribing would allow me to connect a new account, but i can't unsubscribe. I click the "cancel purchase" and always get an error saying "something happend"

I've contacted support, but can only contact billing support, they said the couldn't do anything that I had to contact Sales. Did that and they dispatched me saying the couldn't do anything and send me an email only giving me the option to pay for support.

As this is clearly an error of the platform I refuse to pay for this. I think it is crazy that they have a bug and I have to pay to solve it.

If someone has had a similar issue or know how to solve it, please help. Really need this to work.

Thanks in advance for the time and effort. ;)

Comment: I would pay for support and then ask for a refund once the problem is confirmed to be a Google issue and not an end-user problem.